# Select one row from multiple row in sql depands on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in sql 2008 named tblEmployeeAttendance like 
[image]

Here is some dummy data for a employee's one days attendance like

[image]

Here AI refers AttendanceIn,AO refers AttendanceOut,BO refers BreakIn and BI refers BreakOut.There can multiple row in a day for a employee.First row should be AI,last row should be AO and others rows will be BreakIn,BreakOut Sequentially(that means BreakIn-BreakOut-BreakIn.....).

My expected output would be like this

[image]

I need a sql query that will return one row per date and return data that must contain AttendanceIn and AttendanceOut Time depands on strRemark(AI & AO). Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, I would not reference the column names with "int", "dte" and "str".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 intEmployeeeId,
 dteAttendanceDate as 'Attendance Date'
 min(dteAttendanceTime) as 'Attendance In'
 max(dteAttendanceTime) as 'Attendance Out'
FROM
 tblEmployeeAttendance
GROUP BY
 intEmployeeeId,
 dteAttendanceDate
```

You probably dont need the AI and AO checks as the time will always be at opposite ends of the day.